# How to combine RGB image and 8-bit alpha image into single PNG file with Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

Imagine I have rgb.jpg and alpha.png. How to combine them into rgba.png with Imagemagick?

Answer (score 21):

Since you didn't specify, I'll assume a sufficiently new version of ImageMagick being run from the command line. This was tested using ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 on Linux (from [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/imagemagick)).

If `alpha.png` is an image from which you want to copy the alpha channel, or it is a greyscale image with no alpha channel, you can use the following:

```
convert rgb.jpg alpha.png -compose copy-opacity -composite rgba.png
```

Otherwise, you will have to do a bit more processing on `alpha.png`. For example, this converts `alpha.png` to greyscale and ignores the alpha channel:

```
convert rgb.jpg ( alpha.png -colorspace gray -alpha off ) -compose copy-opacity -composite rgba.png
```

Note that you may have to escape the parentheses in the latter command, depending on your command-line environment.

If necessary, you can also invert the greyscale image before using it as the alpha channel:

```
convert rgb.jpg ( alpha.png -colorspace gray -alpha off -negate ) -compose copy-opacity -composite rgba.png
```